# Redirect to an action from Application_BeginRequest in global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

In my web application I am validating  the url from glabal.asax . I want to validate the url and need to redirect to an action if needed. I am using Application_BeginRequest to catch the request event.

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If the product is not registered then
        // redirect the user to product registraion page.
        if (Application[ApplicationVarInfo.ProductNotRegistered] != null)
        {
             //HOW TO REDIRECT TO ACTION (action=register,controller=product)
         }
     }
```

Or is there any other way to validate each url while getting requests in mvc and redirect to an action if needed

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580728/redirecting-from-global-asax-in-medium-trust

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the below code for redirection

```
   Response.RedirectToRoute("Default");
```

"Default" is route name. If you want to redirect to any action,just create a route and use that route name .

Comment: This will create a loop

Comment: @Null Pointer, please could you accept one of the other answers that works?

Comment: This causes a redirect loop to occur if used in the Application_beginRequest function.

Answer (score 30):

All above will not work you will be in the loop of executing the method `Application_BeginRequest`.

You need to use

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Home/About");
```

Answer (score 14):

Besides the ways mentioned already. Another way is using URLHelper which I used in a scenario once error happend and User should be redirected to the Login page :

```
public void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e){
    try{
         if(!Request.IsAuthenticated){
            throw  new InvalidCredentialException("The user is not authenticated.");
        }
    } catch(InvalidCredentialException e){
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
        Response.Redirect(urlHelper.Action("Login", "Account"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That causes another request. Which in turns makes another,. Which makes another. And so on when you're in the application_begin request function.

Comment: @RichardBarker This code is not located in application_begin request!!!! I put it in  Application_PostAuthenticateRequest an in the catch block in cas error happend

Comment: My apologies. The question showed BeginRequest. May I suggest you update your answer to show that and explain why you did it?

Comment: That's a bit better, but I created a short complete code example from your update. That will help future stackers by making it easier to understand and also utilize. I believe this to be the best solution for the issue described in the OP - it will avoid the loop issue but first it needs one more check for the current request being for the login action.

Comment: I like this as it generates the MVC route from the helper and will inherently handle a change to the routing. I'm never comfortable hard coding MVC routes as strings!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("...");
```

Answer (score 5):

I do it like this:

```
        HttpContextWrapper contextWrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(this.Context);

        RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "FirstVisit");

        IController controller = new HomeController();

        RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(contextWrapper, routeData);

        controller.Execute(requestContext);
        Response.End();
```

this way you wrap the incoming request context and redirect it to somewhere else without redirecting the client. So the redirect won't trigger another BeginRequest in the global.asax.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Response.RedirectToRoute(
                                new RouteValueDictionary {
                                    { "Controller", "Home" },
                                    { "Action", "TimeoutRedirect" }}  );
```

Comment: This will cause another request; which will cause another request. Which causes another request. Which creates another. Until it errors out completely.

Answer (score 0):

I had an old web forms application I had to convert to MVC 5 and one of the requirements was supporting possible {old_form}.aspx links.  In Global.asax Application_BeginRequest I set up a switch statement to handle old pages to redirect to the new ones and to avoid the possible undesired looping to the home/default route check for ".aspx" in the request's raw URL.

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OldPageToNewPageRoutes();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provide redirects to new view in case someone has outdated link to .aspx pages
    /// </summary>
    private void OldPageToNewPageRoutes()
    {
        // Ignore if not Web Form:
        if (!Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains(".aspx"))
            return;

        // Clean up any ending slasshes to get to the old web forms file name in switch's last index of "/":
        var removeTrailingSlash = VirtualPathUtility.RemoveTrailingSlash(Request.RawUrl);
        var sFullPath = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(removeTrailingSlash)
            ? removeTrailingSlash.ToLower()
            : Request.RawUrl.ToLower();
        var sSlashPath = sFullPath;

        switch (sSlashPath.Split(Convert.ToChar("/")).Last().ToLower())
        {
            case "default.aspx":
                Response.RedirectToRoute(
                    new RouteValueDictionary
                    {
                        {"Controller", "Home"},
                        {"Action", "Index"}
                    });
                break;
            default:
                // Redirect to 404:
                Response.RedirectToRoute(
                    new RouteValueDictionary
                    {
                        {"Controller", "Error"},
                        {"Action", "NotFound"}
                    });
                break;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i prefer not use Web.config. Then i created code above in Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

        //Not Found (When user digit unexisting url)
        if(ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() == 404)
        {
            HttpContextWrapper contextWrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(this.Context);

            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "NotFound");

            IController controller = new ErrorController();
            RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(contextWrapper, routeData);
            controller.Execute(requestContext);
            Response.End();
        }
        else //Unhandled Errors from aplication
        {
            ErrorLogService.LogError(ex);
            HttpContextWrapper contextWrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(this.Context);

            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");

            IController controller = new ErrorController();
            RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(contextWrapper, routeData);
            controller.Execute(requestContext);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

And thtat is my ErrorController.cs

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // GET: Error
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        return View("~/Views/Shared/SAAS/Error.cshtml", ex);
    }

    public ViewResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View("~/Views/Shared/SAAS/NotFound.cshtml");
    }
}
```

And that is my ErrorLogService.cs based on mason class

```
//common service to be used for logging errors
public static class ErrorLogService
{
    public static void LogError(Exception ex)
    {
        //Do what you want here, save log in database, send email to police station
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can try with this:

Context.Response.Redirect();

Nt sure.